# Laravel Chumper Zipper - Won't extract to my path

Tags: php, laravel-5, zip

I want to extract a few zip files to this folder:

> /backend/storage/app

The absoloute path of my hosting server would be:

> var/www/hosts/radlvoo/backend/storage/app

This is my code for the Chumper Zipper so far:

```
Zipper::make('radlvoo.zip'))->extractTo('backend/storage/app');
```

But it doesn't work. PHP is not even crashing, the folder and file simply doesn't exists... But I have no idea why..

Could anybody please help me?

Kind regards